# Can constant exposure to static electricity affect the nervous system in any way?

Tags: brain, neurology, nerves, electricity, central-nervous-system

As titled, can holding a constant static charge affect the CNS? If so, is it detrimental? What are the short/long term effects, if any?

Comment: Laptops do not produce static electricity, or any other sort of electricity in the outer shell where you can touch it. I don't know what you're feeling, but it's not electricity.

Comment: @CareyGregory when its plugged in it does. in my case it does

Comment: Then you have a laptop with a dangerous short circuit. I would suggest you stop using it.

Comment: @CareyGregory meh that really isn't helpful. to the question though. and isnt a short circuit, i been using it for a very long time now.

Comment: It simply is not normal for a laptop to have an electrical charge anywhere on the exterior. So if you're going to insist that there is then I'm going to vote to close as off topic and refer you to Superuser to figure out what's wrong with your laptop. So perhaps you could clarify what health question you're asking that doesn't involve defective electronics.

Comment: @CareyGregory the question is still legit. im not asking doubts about my laptop am i?

Comment: The title of your question is a legitimate health question. The rest of it is off topic either because it's about your laptop or it's a request for personal medical advice. You can rescue the question by editing it. Delete everything about your laptop and simply ask the question contained in the title. That's my last comment on this other than simply downvoting and voting to close.

Comment: @CareyGregory that will leave a simple question without a proper scenario example..

Comment: I removed your scenario, my edit would make it a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of research, I will give a few physics observations.

Generally, voltage is considered to be relative. So electrical engineers for example completely disregard static charge in most engineering applications.

The exception where static charge is relevant is when there is a risk of *discharge*, i.e. a discharge shock. That can damage equipment. It's known as well that electrical currents can damage tissue and cause cardiac arrest. So for example if you are electrically charged, then discharging in a way that passes significant current through the heart could be dangerous. However static charges would be small in day to day tasks, because of the small capacity of the body to hold the charges and high internal resistance (a greater capacitance would mean more charge at the same voltage). Maybe holding a highly capacitive object (such as a literal capacitor terminal) could change this consideration.

But the static undischarged charge itself is unlikely to have any physiological effects at all because of insensitivity of most materials and processes to absolute potential (some exceptions include semiconductors). The electric field inside the body should be negligible and charge would concentrate on the skin. The physics of internal processes stays largely the same whether you are at absolute +1000V relative to Earth (ground) or at +0V relative to Earth, although in the first case the discharge could lead to a nasty shock (likely not lethal if you're floating/not connected to any power source, probably lethal otherwise).

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers must be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.